# Can't use ToOADate() in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I've ran up against a frustrating little issue when knocking together a page in C# and Silverlight (v5): I can't use the `DateTime.ToOADate()` function! Intellisense doesn't "see" it when typing, and if I manually type it anyway:

```
double OAdate()
{          
    double oadate= DateTime.ToOADate();
    return oadate;
}
```

.. I'm told:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'System.DateTime.ToOADate()'

I know I'm doing something daft ... but what? `FromOADate()` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have date time object to call [`ToOADate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate) method.

ToOADate is Convert the value of **instance** to the equivalent OLE Automation date. it **not a static method** like [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx)

try

```
DateTime.Now.ToOADate();
```

or

```
 DateTime MyDate = new  DateTime(1904, 12, 12, 1,4,1);
 double MyDouble = MyDate.ToOADate();
```

Comment: How embarrassing ... I could have sworn I'd tried that; too much code and not enough sleep :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear, you need to initialize the DateTime first, then you can use this method.